# C# Task.Kill() not available

Tags: c#, task

I don't know how i can kill my Task ?

```
    private Task ReadSerialUART;

    public void StartSerial()
    {
        ReadSerialUART = new Task(ReadSerial);
    }

    public void StopSerial()
    {
        //?? ReadSerialUART.Kill();
    }
    public void ReadSerial()
    {            
        char Key;
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            Key = (char)this.SerialPort.ReadChar();
            if (Key != 13)
            {
                this.trans.richTextBox_message.Invoke(new Action(() => this.trans.richTextBox_message.Text += Key));
            }
        }            
    }
```

I tried it with .Kill(), but it's not avialable. I can't create a global variable too, because the ReadSerial() while loop waits at ReadChar().

Comment: Lookup Task cancellation in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `SerialPort.Close` should cause `ReadChar` to abort with an exception. (Not tested.) *Then* you test for the global variable to exit the loop (which you also need). Oh, and you're really abusing `Task` here, since this "task" is neither asynchronous nor properly cancellable. May as well use a thread.

Comment: "waits at ReadChar()" is your problem here. Tasks can't be killed, Threads shouldn't be.

Comment: `ReadSerial` is public, and could be called concurrently by multiple threads. If you instead decide to keep it private and have only accesible from the task, and doing so preventing the mentioned problem... you might aswell make it a local function and then use captured local variable to break the loop, a CancellationToken would be easy to support then. Addendum: I would still worry about the initalization of `SerialPort`.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem but you really ought to be passing `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to an appropriate `Task` constructor if you're planning to run an infinite loop in that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `ReadChar()` to block pernamently use `ReadTimeout` property. Modified version of your code:

```
 private Task ReadSerialUART;

public void StartSerial()
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource(); // create token source
    ReadSerialUART = new Task(() => ReadSerial(source)); //start task
    Thread.Sleep(5000) //lets wait some time before cancelling task

    source.Cancel(); // you can cancel task by calling this anytime
}

public void StopSerial()
{
    //?? ReadSerialUART.Kill();
}
public void ReadSerial(CancellationToken token)
{            
    char Key;
    SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000; // with this ReadChar() will throw TimeoutException after 1 sec
    while (1 == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            Key = (char)this.SerialPort.ReadChar();
        }finally
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // ternimate thread if token is canceled (source.cancel() is called)
        }

        if (Key != 13)
        {
            this.trans.richTextBox_message.Invoke(new Action(() => 
            this.trans.richTextBox_message.Text += Key));
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
    // Start notepad.
    Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    // Wait one second.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // End notepad.
    process.Kill();
```

Add this line to your using list:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Get a list of the processes with the Process.GetProcesses() method, as seen below

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

 foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, 
           theprocess.Id);
 }
```

you have to wait for some time to kill any process.
when you are going to start any process and want to kill it than use some sleep time between them